# How to traverse a Python List and its List elements , splitting strings within each element and writing out a new list

Tags: python, list, nested, traversal

I have a list comprising hundreds of elements, many of which are themselves a list. I am looking to "flatten" and dedupe the list and write it out to file.  Discrete elements that should be written to the flattened list are delimited in the source data by a double backslash "\".  As an example, given the following list:

```
alist = ["ZZ Ward\\Eric Bell"],["ZZ Ward"],["Sabine Kabongo\\Salif Keita\\Cat Stevens\\Trilok Gurtu\\Lindsey Buckingham"], ["John Mellencamp\\Cat Stevens"]
```

I am looking to create a new list that comprises the following:

```
ZZ Ward
Eric Bell
Sabine Kabongo
Salif Keita
Cat Stevens
Trilok Gurtu
Lindsey Buckingham
John Mellencamp
```

Being new to Python I've done a lot of searching and tried various approaches but haven't quite managed to get to the correct solution.

Using the following code:

```
alist = ["ZZ Ward\\Eric Bell"],["ZZ Ward"],["Sabine Kabongo\\Salif Keita\\Cat Stevens\\Trilok Gurtu\\Lindsey Buckingham"], ["John Mellencamp\\Cat Stevens"]
alist = list(filter(None, alist))
alist.sort()
for list in alist:
  for element in list:
  print(type(element), element.split("\\"))
```

I've managed to get as far as this:

```
<class 'str'> ['John Mellencamp', 'Cat Stevens']
<class 'str'> ['Sabine Kabongo', 'Salif Keita', 'Cat Stevens', 'Trilok Gurtu', 'Lindsey Buckingham']
<class 'str'> ['ZZ Ward']
<class 'str'> ['ZZ Ward', 'Eric Bell']
```

Whilst the deduping should be relatively simple, how do I convert this individual entries to a List with no elements themselves being a list?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `list comprehension` with `set`:

```
>>> new_list = [l3 for l1 in alist for l2 in l1 for l3 in l2.split('\\')]
>>> new_list
['ZZ Ward', 'Eric Bell', 'ZZ Ward', 'Sabine Kabongo', 'Salif Keita', 'Cat Stevens', 'Trilok Gurtu', 'Lindsey Buckingham', 'John Mellencamp', 'Cat Stevens']
>>> list(set(new_list))
['ZZ Ward', 'Salif Keita', 'Eric Bell', 'Lindsey Buckingham', 'Trilok Gurtu', 'Sabine Kabongo', 'John Mellencamp', 'Cat Stevens']
# If maintaining order is necessary:
>>> sorted(set(new_list), key=new_list.index)
['ZZ Ward', 'Eric Bell', 'Sabine Kabongo', 'Salif Keita', 'Cat Stevens', 'Trilok Gurtu', 'Lindsey Buckingham', 'John Mellencamp']
```

FWIW basically a `set comprehension` would do, if order is not required:

```
>>> {l3 for l1 in alist for l2 in l1 for l3 in l2.split('\\')}
{'Cat Stevens',
 'Eric Bell',
 'John Mellencamp',
 'Lindsey Buckingham',
 'Sabine Kabongo',
 'Salif Keita',
 'Trilok Gurtu',
 'ZZ Ward'}
```

In traditional version this can be done like this:

```
new_list = []
for l1 in alist:
    for l2 in l1:
        for l3 in l2.split('\\'):
            if l3 not in new_list:
                new_list.append(l3)
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
['ZZ Ward', 'Eric Bell', 'Sabine Kabongo', 'Salif Keita', 'Cat Stevens', 'Trilok Gurtu', 'Lindsey Buckingham', 'John Mellencamp']
```

Answer (score 0):

List Comprehension is the best way to do this but if you continue down the path you started I think this would solve the problem.

```
alist = ["ZZ Ward\\Eric Bell"],["ZZ Ward"],["Sabine Kabongo\\Salif Keita\\Cat Stevens\\Trilok Gurtu\\Lindsey Buckingham"], ["John Mellencamp\\Cat Stevens"]
alist = list(filter(None, alist))
alist.sort()
for list in alist:
  for element in list:
      for item in element.split("\\"):
          print(type(item), item)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, use `sum` to flatten your list.

```
>>> sum(alist, [])
['ZZ Ward\\Eric Bell', 'ZZ Ward', 'Sabine Kabongo\\Salif Keita\\Cat Stevens\\Trilok Gurtu\\Lindsey Buckingham', 'John Mellencamp\\Cat Stevens']
```

then you can concatenate all the list entries into one string with the same delimiter:

```
>>> "\\".join(sum(alist, []))
'ZZ Ward\\Eric Bell\\ZZ Ward\\Sabine Kabongo\\Salif Keita\\Cat Stevens\\Trilok Gurtu\\Lindsey Buckingham\\John Mellencamp\\Cat Stevens'
```

After you have that, you can split them using the delimiter:

```
>>> "\\".join(sum(alist, [])).split("\\")
['ZZ Ward', 'Eric Bell', 'ZZ Ward', 'Sabine Kabongo', 'Salif Keita', 'Cat Stevens', 'Trilok Gurtu', 'Lindsey Buckingham', 'John Mellencamp', 'Cat Stevens']
```

Now once you have that, you can remove duplicates with the set constructor, as suggested in the previous answer:

```
>>> set("\\".join(sum(alist, [])).split("\\"))
{'Trilok Gurtu', 'Sabine Kabongo', 'Lindsey Buckingham', 'Salif Keita', 'ZZ Ward', 'Eric Bell', 'Cat Stevens', 'John Mellencamp'}
```

So you see all the manipulations you wanted can be accomplished in a single line!

```
newlist = set("\\".join(sum(alist, [])).split("\\"))
```